# Highlight year in author-year label

Tags: biblatex

I need to boldface the year of publication in the bibliography.
Using biblatex with the built-in author-year, I found the line

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\emph{#1}}
```

in the official documentation.
So I figured that

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{year}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
```

should do the trick.
However, using it as shown in the MWE below, this doesn't affect the way the bibliography is rendered (and neither does the title italicisation).

What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{porter:1980,
  author = "Porter, Martin F.",
  journal = "Program",
  title = "An algorithm for suffix stripping",
  year = "1980"
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{year}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\begin{document}
As stated by \textcite{porter:1980}\dots
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want the year to be boldface only in the bibliography, or also in citations?

Comment: Actually, I need this for creating a stand-alone bibliography list without citations, using a series of `\fullcite` commands. However, your answer (you're going to write one, aren't you?) might be more valuable to future readers if you include both versions.

Comment: Yes, I'll look at it tomorrow. I don't think the citations years should be in boldface, that's the difficulty (at least for me…).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are actually seeing here is not the year field, but `labelyear`, so you would have to do

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelyear}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
```

That, however, changes only the citations and does in most cases not affect the bibliography. In the bibliography the year is most often printed as part of a date via a `\print...date...` macro. Modifications to the field formats do not affect the  `\print...date...` macros. Here, a very easy solution is

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{yearinbib}{\mkbibbold{\mkbibparens{#1}}}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[yearinbib]{%
       \iffieldsequal{year}{labelyear}
         {\printlabeldateextra}%
         {\printfield{labelyear}%
          \printfield{extrayear}}}}}
```

With the upcoming version 3.8 of `biblatex` that code changes to

```
\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[yearinbib]{%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\printdateextra}
         {\printlabeldateextra}}}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelyear}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{yearinbib}{\mkbibbold{\mkbibparens{#1}}}

\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[yearinbib]{%
       \iffieldsequal{year}{labelyear}
         {\printlabeldateextra}%
         {\printfield{labelyear}%
          \printfield{extrayear}}}}}

\begin{document}
As stated by \textcite{sigfridsson}\dots
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great, even without the `labeldateparts` package option (despite the docs saying so). I still don't quite understand why it didn't work for the title either, as it is not part of the label (I don't need it, I'm just curious).

Comment: @lenz It doesn't work for `title`s of `@article`s because they have a special type-specific format which can only be overwritten by `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\emph{#1}}`. `\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibbold{#1}}` will work for types without type-specific formats, e.g. `@book`s. `labeldateparts` is automatically set to `true` by the `authoryear` style.

Comment: I see. Dang, there are just too many interdependencies in an elaborate bibliography/citation system... I'm glad I'm not the maintainer of `biblatex`, it's hard enough as a user.